# Why would adipose tissue be the most essential ingredient in achieving flight?

Tags: magic, flight, transportation

Witches have two means of achieving flight. One is through enchanting items such as broomsticks. The other is through a liquid referred to as "flying ointment". This ointment is made by mixing various ingredients, such as juices of smallage, wolfe-bane, and cinque foil, mingled with the meal of fine wheat. However, it's most important ingredient is adipose tissue from the fat of humans.

Adipose tissue is a specialized connective tissue consisting of lipid-rich cells called adipocytes. As it comprises about 20-25% of total body weight in healthy individuals, the main function of adipose tissue is to store energy in the form of lipids (fat). Another purpose that it can be used for is as a form of biodiesel fuel. After rubbing this ointment into themselves, witches are able to achieve flight capability.

The dark ages certainly is not lacking of dead bodies. Constant warfare between countries, the black death, and rampant poverty all make this period in history ripe pickings for material. People even sell the fat of dead criminals executed for their crimes at the market to return a hefty profit. However, the most valuable material comes from the fat of infants. Witches take to kidnapping babies from home or even buying wanted mouths to feed from destitute parents or entire villages struggling to make a living.

Why would it be the case that the fat of infants are better materials for flying ointments?

Comment: Attention. Dark/Middle Ages were like 500 to 1200. Witch hunts were around 1500 to 1700. They were fuelled by the advent of the printer press, which permitted to spread rumours much faster. Don't mix things up if it is not in express.

Answer (score 3):

**Brown Adipose Tissue**

Babies have a naturally higher amount of this particular fat.

"Brown adipose tissue is especially abundant in newborns and in hibernating mammals. It is also present and metabolically active in adult humans, but its prevalence decreases as humans age. Its primary function is thermoregulation. In addition to heat produced by shivering muscle, brown adipose tissue produces heat by non-shivering thermogenesis." [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_adipose_tissue)

This kind of tissue is also used for hibernating animals. I think it is fair to say that the primary use of such tissue in flying ointment is that it is much easier to convert to other forms of energy. Especially because its part of a "seasonal" fat for most creatures and should be easy to lose those extra pounds once hibernation is over.

**How can my witch utilise it?**

Babies would naturally have more. However, in spring/fall, they could gather much larger amounts from animals entering or leaving hibernation and it would be much cheaper and less suspicious to purchase animal fat than to purchase newborns.

Answer (score 1):

Law of Similarity

Fat floats on water and counterbalances the denser parts of the human body.  The witch wishes to float on air.

Furthermore, the smaller something is, the more easily it is blown away by the air.  Although no human is small enough to spontaneously be borne off, the similarity means the lighter the person the more effective the fat is.  Even a smaller adult would be detectable better than a large one, though no witch has bothered to study that far, given the far large size difference available.

Answer (score 0):

In most stories I've read, these "witches" are satanic rather than pagan. As such, their magic might be founded on how perverse the ritual/ingredients/etc are. And almost universally, the murder of babies is considered a far more heinous crime than the murder of adults.

Thus an ingredient from not just a baby, but possibly several (as you can imagine, actual fat among babies in that day and age was... scarce, so you might need more than one). Why this ingredient and not another? Difficult to say.

But remember first and foremost, this particular mythology was invented and designed to persecute, and entertainment was a distant runner-up. Logic wasn't even in the race, so to speak. Details would be chosen to horrify or perhaps occasionally for their absurdity. In the pre-scientific age, no one bothered to try to invent detail that had internal consistency. Trying to impose that upon these stories after the fact can be futile.